# Cannot run Enthought python

Tags: python, enthought

I am using a 32 bit Windows 7 system and I just installed the Canopy Enthought Python(1.0.1)
However I am not be able to run it properly, as I got some message like below:

"The kernel (user Python environment) has terminated with error code 1. This may be due to a bug in your code or in the kernel itself.

Output captured from the kernel process is shown below.

```
ValueError: invalid \x escape"
```

I currently have no idea what is happening, I noticed my user name is xp, would that be relevant here? I tried to reinstall but nothing helps.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Wild guess: are you using the compatible version of python, 2 or 3?

Comment: @user1850672 I downloaded the Canopy Enthought Python from here https://www.enthought.com/downloads/, whichever version that maybe.

Comment: @Tao: I'd recommend that you contact Enthought about this issue.  If their installer hasn't worked for you then they have a problem.

Comment: @user1850672: Enthought Canopy *includes* Python 2.7. It's an installer which installs Python 2.7 and a whole bunch of mathematical and scientific Python packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tao, it sounds as if your Windows user name (and hence your HOME path) contains non-ASCII characters. Is this true? At present, Canopy cannot correctly install under these circumstances. The current (unsatisfactory) workaround is to install and use Canopy when logged in with an ASCII user name. Apologies for the inconvenience.

https://support.enthought.com/entries/23707691-Canopy-GUI-cannot-finish-setup-when-user-s-home-path-contains-non-ASCII-characters